# Good Linux distro with common command-line utils

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distribution

While debugging issues in Kubernetes, there are times when I need to install a pod, exec into it and poke around the cluster. This can be done pretty easily with a command like `kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu -- bash`.

However, Ubuntu doesn't come out of the box with even basic tooling like `ping` or `nmap`. Typically the problems I'm solving are network-related so I end up installing those a lot.

Is there a distribution I can use instead that is basically Ubuntu with commonly used tooling?

Comment: Can't you add the dependencies needed in a VM startup script?  For example put `apt install -y nmap` in such a script. This way the pacckages have already been installed when you first log in.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want Red Hat Linux or its free version, Centos OS. For instance: [Kubernetes&CentOS_install](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-centos-8/).

I just read that you want a Ubuntu variant. That would be Ubuntu server?